# How to import `fastly:env` into a Fastly Compute@Edge build

Tags: typescript, webassembly, fastly-compute

I've got a fresh Fastly Compute@Edge project that fails the moment I try to import `fastly:env`.

It's a fresh Remix project. Nothing fancy. Everything builds fine except for `fastly:env`. It says that it can't find `fastly:env` in `node_modules`. The TS type definitions are all there, but I don't know enough about WASM imports to debug it.

I filed a GitHub issue against my own project: https://github.com/highlight/remix-on-fastly/issues/1

[image: In short,]